# Candy Button Paper

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, optimization

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337). Title based on [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/205/).</sup>

---

Your biggest dream has come true: you have an infinite supply of your favorite five-flavor candy button paper. Unfortunately, you are a very picky eater. In fact, you are so picky that it is physically impossible for you to eat the same flavor pattern twice in a row. For example, if we label the flavors a-e, and you eat `aebceb`, then it is impossible for you to eat flavor `b` (can't repeat `b`) or `c` (can't repeat `ebc`) next. But you can eat `a`, `d`, or `e` next.

Question: Is it always possible to eat another candy, regardless of the pattern you've previously eaten? If so, prove it. If not, what is the minimal number of candies you can eat before it is impossible to eat any more, and prove that it is the minimal number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The string $abacabadabacabaeabacabadabacaba$ of length $31$ cannot be extended. To illustrate this, it is obtained recursively as follows: $a$, $aba$, $abacaba$, etc., i.e., inserting the next character between two copies of the string.
>
> Now suppose $x_n$ is a shortest string on $n$ characters $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that for all $i$, $x_n=u_iw_ia_iw_i$ for some strings $u_i$ and $w_i$ (in this problem, we are interested in $n=5$). Choose $u_i$ and $w_i$ such that $|w_i|$ is as small as possible. Without loss of generality, assume that $|w_1|<\dots<|w_n|$. Because $|x_n|$ is minimal, $|u_n|$ must be $0$, i.e., $x_n=w_na_nw_n$.
>
> Suppose that $x_{n-1}$, a shortest string not extendable by $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, is longer than $w_n$. Let $s=w_{n-1}a_{n-1}w_{n-1}$. Because $s$ cannot be extended, $s$ must be at least as long as $x_{n-1}$ and thus longer than $w_n$, so $s$ contains the $a_n$ at the center of $x_n$. Let $w_{n-1}=ya_nz$ such that $y$ and $z$ are strings and $x_n$ ends in $s=ya_nza_{n-1}ya_nz$ where the first $a_n$ coincides with the central $a_n$ of $x_n$ (the central $a_n$ must appear in the first half of $s$ because $|s|\le|x_n|$). Then $w_n$ is everything after this $a_n$, i.e., $za_{n-1}ya_nz$, so $x_n=w_na_nw_n=za_{n-1}ya_nza_nza_{n-1}ya_nz$, but this contains $a_nza_nz$, so you couldn't have eaten $x_n$! Our original assumption that $x_{n-1}$ is longer than $w_n$ was false, so $|x_n|=2|w_n|+1\ge2|x_{n-1}|+1$. Applying this inductively with a base case of $|x_1|=1$, we find that $|x_2|\ge3$, $|x_3|\ge7$, $|x_4|\ge15$, and $|x_5|\ge31$. Hence, the above string achieves the minimum.

Comment: Please let me know if anything is unclear/unjustified!

Comment: Remove the last char from your 31 char solution and add `eb` to obtain `abacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabeb`. Does this string violate the contraint?

Comment: Ahh, the shortest "dead-end" string, I see. Ok : )

Comment: @Kaya Oh, perhaps you misinterpreted (as I did at first) as seeking for the longest possible string with no duplicate, which has an answer of [infinitely long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word).

Comment: Yes, I think that + global repeats vs. adjacent repeats were both confusing me at some point. Carry on : D

Comment: Hi..can you write your solution in a simpler language ? I have studied Maths till the age of 18 but am unable to understand your solution

Comment: How did you realise that xn will be of the form  xn=uiwiaiwi  ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal We want $x_n$ to end in a repeated string if the new candy $a_i$ is appended. That repeated section therefore ends in $a_i$, i.e. it is $w_ia_i$ for some string $w_i$ (which may be an empty string). So $x_n$ with $a_i$ appended ends in $w_ia_iw_ia_i$, hence $x_na_i$ must be  $u_iw_ia_iw_ia_i$ for some $u_i$, making $x_n$ equal to $u_iw_ia_iw_i$ for some (possibly empty) strings $u_i$ and $w_i$.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal The whole point of the question is to find a sequence that cannot be extended without causing a repeat. So whichever candy you append to it, it ends with a repeated sequence of candies.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis , I will ask my queries one by one. Let's look at this line in the answer above.
 
“Because $|x_n|$ is minimal, $|u_n|$ must be $0$, i.e., $x_n=w_na_nw_n$“
 
So, lets take the case when n=5. Let’s call the candies  $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$ and $a_5$,  What does $x_n=w_na_nw_n$ mean ? Does it mean ( when n=5 that) $x_5$= minimum length( $w_1a_1w_1$ ,    $w_2a_2w_2$ ,  $w_3a_3w_3$ ,  $w_4a_4w_4$ ,  $w_5a_5w_5$) ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal No. $x$ will end in a repeat whichever candy is appended to it. The length of the repeated section depends on the candy we append. Label the candy types $a_1$ to $a_5$ in order of the length of the repeat it causes, so $a_5$ gives the longest repeated section. Any candies that are not in that longest repeat also wont be part of the shorter repeats, and therefore are unnecessary. We can skip them and still have a non-extendable sequence. So if $a_5$ is appended, the two repeated sections form the whole string $xa_5$, but that is not the case when another candy is appended.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis , hexomino explained the above answer to me in detail in another post.I think I understand the above answer now. But how does one realise that this is how to approach the question ? is it through mathematical induction ? Or does it have it's origin in cryptography or something ? I ask because this method seems very non-intuitive .